# PowerBI DAX to lookup in another table between two dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

Hello all you beautiful people!

With lots of googling- still cannot solve this simple PowerBI trick. I want to build another table based on two tables - for timesheets - of which one table has the start and end dates of the timesheets month, and the other the timesheets themselves. I want to get a column added to the timesheet to state in which timesheet month it falls. (Timesheet month end is a few days before month's last date, based on day of the week, etc)

Example tables:

Table **cfgTimesheetMnth**:

| Period | tsDateStart | tsDateEnd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202302 | 2023-01-28 | 2023-02-24 |
| 202303 | 2023-02-25 | 2023-03-29 |
| 202304 | 2023-03-30 | 2023-04-26 |

Table **erpPrjTimesheets** :

| EmpNo | tsDate | Hrs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100101 | 2023-03-05 | 7 |
| 100101 | 2023-03-30 | 6 |

**Results Table**. I then want to build a new table in PowerBI that needs to look as such:

Table **verpPrjTimesheets**:

| EmpNo | tsDate | Hrs | tsPeriod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100101 | 2023-03-05 | 7 | 202303 |
| 100101 | 2023-03-30 | 6 | 202304 |

The code in the dataview in PowerBI I started with are:

```
verpPrjTimesheets = 

VAR t1 = SELECTCOLUMNS(erpPrjTimesheets
            , "EmpNo"    , [EmpNo]
            , "tsDate"   , [tsDate]
            , "Hrs"      , [Hrs]
            , "tsPeriod" , LOOKUPVALUE(cfgTimesheetsMnth[Period], cfgTimesheetsMnth[tsDateEnd], erpPrjTimesheets[tsDate])
) RETURN 

t1
```

But the LOOKUPVALUE does not have a command to lookup between two date ranges. So above does not work.

What would be a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
verpPrjTimesheets = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    erpPrjTimesheets, 
    "tsPeriod",
    SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(cfgTimesheetMnth, erpPrjTimesheets[tsDate] >= cfgTimesheetMnth[tsDateStart] && erpPrjTimesheets[tsDate] <= cfgTimesheetMnth[tsDateEnd]), "tsPeriod", cfgTimesheetMnth[Period])
)
```